# ASP.NET Web Pages: Overriding values defined in layout from content pages

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

I'm having issues overriding values defined at the top of my layout page.

For example, if I have this at the top of my layout page:

```
@{
    Page.ShowProgressBar = false;
}
```

And reads the value somewhere in the layout:

```
@ if (Page.ShowProgressBar) {
    // do some processing in the layout
}
```

How can I optionally set

```
@{
    Page.ShowProgressBar = true;
}
```

in a content page?

In other words, I want to **provide a default** for Page.ShowProgressBar in the layout, and override it when needed in a content page.

What this also means is that I **don't want to have to set value** for Page.ShowProgressBar in all content pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Layout page is executed *after* the content page so whatever value you choose to set in the content page will be overwritten by the layout page. You should use a `_PageStart.cshtml` file to set a default value. `_PageStart.cshtml` is executed *before* the content page, so you can override the value in the content page.

Alternatively, you can use *_AppStart.cshtml* file to set an application level variable which you can overwrite anywhere. You can read more about these files here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior

Comment: Thank you. _PageStart.cshtml is what I'm looking for. And thanks again for recommending the resource links.